# How to use react testing library class matcher with scss modules?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, css-modules

I have a React component with a background color that depends on the stage prop passed in. For example, when the stage is "Internal" I am setting the background color using color-primary-light-10 class.

I am using React Testing Library and Jest Dom to test that the correct color is applied:

```
it("should render internal stage using light primary color", () => {
    const {getByTestId} = render(<Background stage={"Internal"} />);
    expect(getByTestId(/background/i)).toHaveClass("color-primary-light-10");
});
```

However, because I am using SCSS modules I get the following error:

```
Expected the element to have class:
  color-primary-light-10
Received:
  stage Background-module-scss__background___3TL4w Background-module-scss__color-primary-light-10___3CLwc
```

I tried reading the [toHaveClass](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveclass) section in Jest Dom documentation but I couldn't figure out how to test this.

How can I test that I apply the correct class when using SCSS modules?

Comment: You could try to import your `styles.module.scss` directly to your test file and then pass the desired class name directly into `.toHaveClass` function as you do when you pass it to your component